# Localize text that is already data binding? WP8

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-phone-8, localized

I have a Longlistselector that is getting the text through data binding. My problem is I need it to be localized so it displays the right language, how is the right way to do it?

I tried the first way that came to my head, but I thought it doesn't work:

**MainPage.cs**

```
_UserAdBL.Add(new UserAdB("{Binding LocalizedResources.UsText01, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"));
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get the value of the `{Binding LocalizedResources.UsText01, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}` XAML binding in C#.

So use `AppResources.UsText01` like so

```
_UserAdBL.Add(new UserAdB(AppResources.UsText01));
```

Comment: The problem is, even if I use the `AppResources.UsText01` @IgorKulman when it shows the binding text, will show the code and not the localizedresource it is supposed to call. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Did you wrap `AppResources.UsText01` in quotes? If so, you shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks @IgorKulman that was the problem, I wrapped the text, didn't realize was different in C# (I'm not familiar with C# so I always try to use more XAML but I am slowly starting to learn more C#.